Spoke: "That email is already taken." - Can't sign up with email address of deleted user on Spoke
I deleted a Spoke user and now they need to use Spoke again. I gave them a link to create a new account but they get the error "That email is already taken." despite not showing up in the user list. How do I fix this?


Please note that questions about web services are not on topic on SuperUser. I recommend you read the Help section to better understand this site and what is and is not on topic.

Websites and web services are off topic on [su].

Shucks I can never get it right which Stack Exchange site to use. I had Chat GPT give me a list of the top 5 sites to use for this question and then I looked into those sites before choosing and guess I still got it wrong.

@AlexanderTaylor, it is better to ask where to ask a question in [meta.se]. P.D. Stack Exchange has several sites related to generative AI. As end-users, [webapps.se] and [genai.se] might be good places to ask questions about using ChatGPT, and [ai.se] for some aspects related to the technical part of crafting prompts.

I was mistaken. The user was not deleted, but suspended, and the UI was confusing, appearing to show all users but actually filtering users as "All roles" does not include "Suspended", which is strangely considered a "role".


